# How to open Bootstrap 5 Modal instantly and then load the AJAX content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The Bootstrap 5 Modal does not open until the AJAX Content is loaded. It's a bad UX for my users as users have to wait few seconds for the modal to open after clicking the `View` button!

So having said that, how can I load the Bootstrap 5 modal load instantly on clicking? Let the AJAX content take 2-3 ore more seconds to load after the modal is opened.

This is the button which triggers the modal: `<button data-id="269" class="view-post">View</button>`

Here's the JS code that loads the modal content:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.view-post', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_post_by_ajax',
            'id': $(this).data('id'),
            'security': blog.security
        };
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#postModal h5#postModalLabel').text(response.title);
            $('#postModal .modal-body').html(response.content);
            var postModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('postModal'));
            postModal.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just call `postModal` before doing the ajax call?.  You could even do -> `$('#postModal .modal-body').html('loading..');` to give your users some feedback.

Comment: How do I do that? Please keep in mind that I'm opening blogs in a modal instead of redirecting user to a different page. So, each Modal has different types of content with images/videos. Loading all those images/videos before the Modal is open will slow down the blog listing page.

Comment: Move the last 2 lines of your ajax callback to before the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @Keith Could you please post your comment as an answer with the complete code? I'm unable to understand. When I place your quote in the last 2 mintes, it only shows "loading..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not used jQuery for a long while, but you should be able to show the dialog, pre-fill with some loading indicator etc, call your ajax, and then when that's complete fill with the new data.

eg.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.view-post', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_post_by_ajax',
            'id': $(this).data('id'),
            'security': blog.security
        };
        //lets have a reference to title & body element
        var title = $('#postModal h5#postModalLabel');
        var body = $('#postModal .modal-body'); 
        //create our modal dialog
        var postModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('postModal'));
        //pre-populate with some loading info.
        title.text('Loading..');
        body.html('Please wait.');
        //now show dialog
        postModal.show();
        //now call ajax post
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            //now update dialog with new data.
            title.text(response.title);
            body.html(response.content);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing. I've been at this for hours! Going through Bootstrap 5 documentations and online resources without success. Thank you so much :)